# How does google analytics collect its data?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

Yes, I know you have to embed the google analytics javascript into your page.

But how is the collected information submitted to the google analytics server?

For example an AJAX request will not be possible because of the browsers security settings (cross domain scripting).

Maybe someone had already a look at the confusing google javascript code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414451/how-does-google-analytics-send-data-back-to-google

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When html page makes a request for a ga.js file the http protocol sends big amount of data, about IP, refer, browers, language, system. There is no need to use ajax.

But still some data cant be achieved this way, so GA script puts image into html with additional parameters, take a look at this example:

`http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.3&utmn=1464271798&utmhn=www.example.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1200&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=10.0%20r22&utmdt=Page title&utmhid=1805038256&utmr=0&utmp=/&utmac=cookie value`

This is a blank image, sometimes called a [tracking pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug), that GA puts into HTML.

Comment: But google-analytics collects a lot more data, e.g. flash version, etc. They are not send with the http headers.

Comment: Yes, but it is done other way than ajax, I added explanation in post.

Comment: Ok, i oversaw utmfl=10.0 for the flash version.
Thx for the explaination.

Comment: It now uses `http(s)://www.google-analytics.com/collect?...` (with other parameter names) to track visits. I can't find documentation about new parameter names.

Comment: What about event trigger-based data. How would GA be sent that information?

Comment: Why can some data not be sent via AJAX? The tracking parameters are obviously put together using JavaScript... Why can't the same parameters be sent via AJAX? Did Google choose the pixel route for efficiency?

Answer (score 9):

Some good answers here which individually tend to hit on one method or another for sending the data. There's a valuable reference which I feel is missing from the above answers, though, and covers all the methods.

Google refers to the different methods of sending data 'transport mechanisms'

From the Analytics.js documentation Google mentions the [three main transport mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport) that it uses to send data.

> This specifies the transport mechanism with which hits will be sent. The options are 'beacon', 'xhr', or 'image'. By default, analytics.js will try to figure out the best method based on the hit size and browser capabilities. If you specify 'beacon' and the user's browser does not support the `navigator.sendBeacon` method, it will fall back to 'image' or 'xhr' depending on hit size.

1. One of the common and standard ways to send some of the data to Google (which is shown in Thinker's answer) is by adding the data as GET parameters to a tracking pixel. This would fall under the category which Google calls an 'image' transport.
2. Secondly, Google can use the 'beacon' transport method if the client's browser supports it. This is often my preferred method because it will attempt to send the information immediately. Or in Google's words:

> This is useful in cases where you wish to track an event just before a user navigates away from your site, without delaying the navigation.

3. The 'xhr' transport mechanism is the third way that Google Analytics can send data back home, and the particular transport mechanism that is used can depend on things such as the size of the hit. (I'm not sure what other factors go into GA deciding the optimal transport mechanism to use)

In case you are curious how to force GA into using a specific transport mechanism, here is a sample code snippet which forces this event hit to be sent as a 'beacon':

```
ga('send', 'event', 'click', 'download-me', {transport: 'beacon'});
```

Hope this helps.

---

Also, if you are curious about this topic because you'd like to capture and send this data to your own site too, I recommend creating a binding to Google Analytics' send, which allows you to grab the payload and AJAX it to your own server.

```
    ga(function(tracker) {

       // Grab a reference to the default sendHitTask function.
       originalSendHitTask = tracker.get('sendHitTask');

       // Modifies sendHitTask to send a copy of the request to a local server after
       // sending the normal request to www.google-analytics.com/collect.
       tracker.set('sendHitTask', function(model) {
         var payload = model.get('hitPayload');
         originalSendHitTask(model);

         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('POST', '/index.php?task=mycollect', true);
         xhr.send(payload);
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Without looking at the code, I assume their data is collected from the HTTP headers they receive in the asynchronous request.

Remember that most browsers send data such as OS, platform, browser, version, locale, etc... Also they do have the IP so they can guesstimate your location. And I assume they have some sort of clever algorithm to decide whether you are a unique visitor or not.

Time on the site is probably calculated by using an `onUnload()` event.

Comment: regarding the onUnload() event, this seems to prove GA doesn't do that: http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help-troubleshoot/browse_thread/thread/d142572ddf1fa9dd/38dd640f949e9890?pli=1

also, go to your GA and check the average time for visits with 1 pageview - it's 0s.

Answer (score 5):

Google Analytics web page provides detailed information of how Google Analytics server collect data. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsOverview.html

All Google Analytics data is collected and packed into the Request URL's query string and sent to Google Analytics server. The http request is made by a gif image(http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif) activated by Google Analytics JS.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough to tell by using something like Firebug's Net tab.

Ajax isn't needed - since data isn't being fetched from Google. They just encode the information in a query string, and then load a transparent gif using it.

Comment: Thats not true, the query string is too short to contain that amount of information. There are only some unique ids and keywords encoded.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on other very good answers, Google does provide an API to track async "virtual pageviews" which are reported by website authors themselves in their scripts to Google.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'my_unique_action']);
```

They provide it so it is possible to track actions that are not part of regular page views and http requests.

Async tracking guide: 
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#Syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use the *httpfox* or *firebug* Firefox extension to figure out what HTTP requests the browser sends and what responses it receives.

I don't know how Google Analytics works, but one possibility is to make the browser download an image: `<img src="http://my-analytics.com" width="1" height="1">` (with a single, transparent pixel), and log all the HTTP request headers (e.g. `Referer:`) on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

//edit: see coment at the bottom

*Ok, find an answer during a discussion with a friend of mine :-)
The informations to google analytics are submitted in three ways:

1. List item
2. The HTTP Request can be analyzed with all informations of the http headers.
3. A cookie is recognized by the google analytics server.
4. **An ajax call is done within the embeded javascript to submit such informations like display resolution, flash player version, etc.** 
   **These informations are not transmitted via the http headers.**
   *This is possible, because the ajax call is done in the context of the embedded javascript, so its no cross domain scripting. This was an error in reasoning by me.**

Comment: Just because the file is sitting on their servers does not magically give it the power to make an XMLHttpRequest to their servers.