# how does google analytics calculate metrics like "average time spent"?

Tags: search, google-analytics

how services like google analytics calculate parameters like

"**average time spent**"
"number of users that came to the website via search Vs user that hit the **url directly**
etc.

I would imagine that google can easily record a HIT when someone clicks on a link in serach result. But after that how long and deep the user is brwosing that perticular website is out of tap...hmmmm ?

Comment: Despite popular opinion, Google are just as evil as any other when it comes to tracking down as much data as they possibly can and wringing value out of it. In this case, they're not above running scripts for the duration of the page view. Who knows what other crap they send back for their own consumption?

Comment: You say 'Google', but analytics is still a script that is added to a page by the webmaster themselves.. So yes there might be a script running in the background, but it's the webmaster that put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892049/how-does-google-analytics-collect-its-data) has some information. As mentioned in that question time should be calculated using an onUnload() event. When the js is loaded firstime the time may be recorded (in cookies)and then onUnload() the time spent is calculated and sent to Google for record.

The above question explains most of your question.

Answer (score 2):

This thread states quite clearly that there is no unLoad() event: http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help-troubleshoot/browse_thread/thread/d142572ddf1fa9dd/38dd640f949e9890?pli=1

Also, try going to GA and look for sessions with only 1 pageview - you will see the average page time is 0s, which proves the point.