# XMLHttpRequest to get HTTP response from remote host

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Why the following code [Based on Mozilla example](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest) does not work? Tried with Firefox 3.5.7 & Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
  <script>
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org/', false); 
    req.send();
    if(req.status == 200) {
        alert(req.responseText);
    }
  </script>  
</html>
```

Please that the browser is pulling the html from local disk (file:///C:/Users/Maxim%20Veksler/Desktop/XMLHTTP.html)

On Firefox it gives the following error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Users/Maxim%20Veksler/Desktop/XMLHTTP.html :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 10" data: no]
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to submit a request to remote host and alert the result (later to added into a div).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your browser is preventing [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You have to use a relative path, otherwise most browsers will simply return an error or an empty responseText.

The following Stack Overflow post is probably also related to your problem:

- [Empty responseText from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941340/).

Comment: OK, so how does google analytics integration javascript code works?

Comment: @Maxim: You may want to check out this SO post: **How does google analytics collect its data?**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892049/how-does-google-analytics-collect-its-data

Answer (score 3):

I'm also assuming that you've opened your HTML test page directly in the browser judging by your reference to `file:///...`. For `XMLHttpRequest` calls, you need to serve the HTML from a server. Try something like xampp (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to get a local server up and running and then run your test from `http://localhost/XMLHTTP.html`.

Note, this does not solve your same-origin problem, but this would allow the following code to work:

```
  <script>
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', '/myTestResponse.html', false); 
    req.send();
    if(req.status == 200) {
        alert(req.responseText);
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Security issue no?

Presumably firefox is preventing the local file from talking to a remote host?

Scouting round the net - found this.  Try adding this to the start of your script:

```
try {
  netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
} catch (e) {
  alert("Permission UniversalBrowserRead denied.");
}
```

Can't guarantee this'll work; because ultimately what you're trying to do is enter a security hole that browsers have been specifically coded to have plugged up (cross-domain requests).

There are some special scenarios where it can be switched on, though, usually at the user's discretion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make requests across domains, even with local files.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

**Unless** you are developing an extension, which does not have the same restrictions as a web page.