# About Google Analytics collect data

Tags: javascript, logging, google-analytics

First of all, Hi to all of you (I'm new here).

I'm having a look on how Google Analytics works as I'm gonna develop a similar tracking js to collect all the data I need for my websites and, as far as I can see, the ga.js script send all the data (maybe not all but a good part of it) with a get request with a 1x1 gif and all the parameters following.

Seen here: [How does google analytics collect its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892049/how-does-google-analytics-collect-its-data)

So, on the server side It seems the only way to "read" all these parameters is going to analyze server logging and then collect everything on my database?

Is this the best option to get users data?

I think, server logging could "switch file" every 2 hours so you can analyze that file of the past 2 hours and show "not that old" data to your graph!

Of course will never be "realtime" graph but a 2 hours delay could be acceptable, I think.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for stackoverflow (since it's not about any specific issue but rather a broad "how do I.." type of question), but I would encourage you to have a look at the existing open source packages (Piwik, Snowplough, OWA etc.). It might be of more value for everyone including yourself if you study and eventually contribute to an existing package rather than solving the problem independently on more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply put a script (PHP for example) at the image path, then through the script return as a response the image, by doing this you can act in real time, since using a script you can get all the data that would be present in your server log.
If you want to try my solution I think a good point to start (in PHP) would be [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) to create the GIF image and then you can use data located in $_SERVER to start gathering data!