# How is Google analytics implemented?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

I mean how google analytics gathering data from client side.

My guess is that GA put js code in client side, and using the js as interceptor to send client data to data gathering server using ajax before user do anything in client side.

Do my guess right?

Comment: You might want to ask Google instead of guessing.

Comment: Try [Googling](http://tinyurl.com/antwem) for it. Which leads to [code site](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html).

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414451/how-does-google-analytics-send-data-back-to-google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that ga.js makes a request for a 1x1 .gif file, and in the request for that gif, it passes along all the parameters used by analytics, such as screen resolution, operating system etc.

*Update: Screenshot from google chrome below*

[image: Request Screenshot]